# IIS 8.5 is not able to trace the Website Visitor IP Address

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I am working with IIS 8.5 on Window 2012 and using IIS Logging feature to get the Visitor IP Address. However, I am not able to see the Visitor IP Address.

**RAW**

```
2018-04-04 00:00:13 W3SVC8 1**.2**.1**.*5 GET /blog/36 - 80 - - Mozilla/5.0+(Linux;+Android+5.1.1;+A37fw+Build/LMY47V;+wv)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/4.0+Chrome/63.0.3239.111+Mobile+Safari/537.36+[FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/153.0.0.54.88;] http://m.facebook.com/ 200 0 0 21277 537 1089
```

**BREAK DOWN**

```
date ---> 2018-04-04
time ---> 00:00:13
s-sitename ---> W3SVC8
s-ip ---> 1**.2**.1**.*5
cs-method ---> GET
cs-uri-stem ---> /blog/36
cs-uri-query ---> -
s-port ---> 80
cs-username ---> -
c-ip ---> -
cs(User-Agent) ---> Mozilla/5.0+(Linux;+Android+5.1.1;+A37fw+Build/LMY47V;+wv)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/4.0+Chrome/63.0.3239.111+Mobile+Safari/537.36+[FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/153.0.0.54.88;]
cs(Referer) ---> http://m.facebook.com/
sc-status ---> 200
sc-substatus ---> 0
sc-win32-status ---> 0
sc-bytes ---> 21277
cs-bytes ---> 537
time-taken ---> 1089
```

[image]

Comment: Did you enable client ip-address logging in the "Select Fields"  menu?

Comment: Thanks! I have referred the following and fixed the issue.https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/configure-logging-in-iis